# How to return each thread's output into an array using OpenMP?

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I would like to proceed a multi-thread program where each thread outputs an array of unknown number of elements.

For example, select all numbers that < 10 from an int array and put them into a new array.

Pseudo code (8 threads):

```
  int *hugeList = malloc(10000000);
  for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
  {
      hugeList[i] = (rand() % 100);//random integers from 0 to 99
  }
  long *subList[8];//to fill each thread's result
  #pragma omp parallel
  for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
  {
     long n = 0;
     if(hugeList[i] < 10)
     {
        //do something to fill "subList" properly
        subList[threadNo][n] = hugeList[i];
        n++;
     }
  }
```

Array "subList" should collect the elements in "hugeList" which satisfies condition (<10) ,sequentially and in terms of thread number.

How should I write the code? It is OK if there is a better way using OpenMP.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

1/ omp pragma should be parallel for, if you want the for loop to be parallelized. Otherwise, code will be duplicated in everay thread.

2/ code is incoherent with comment

```
  //do something to fill "subList" properly
   hugeList[i] = subList[threadNo][n];
```

3/ How do you know the number of element in your sublists? It must be returned to main thread. You could use an array, but beware of false sharing. Better use a local var and write it at the end the parallel section.

4/ sublist is not allocated. The difficulty is that you do not know the number of threads. You can ask omp the max number of thread  (get_omp_max_thread), and do dynamic allocation. If you want some static allocation, maybe the best is to allocate a large table and to compute the actual address in every thread.

5/ omp code must also work without an openmp compiler. Use #ifdef _OPENMP for that.

Here is an (untested) way your code can be written

```
#define HUGE 10000000
int *hugeList = (int *) malloc(HUGE);
#ifdef _OPENMP
int thread_nbr=omp_get_max_threads();
#else
int thread_nbr=1; // to ensure proper behavior in a sequential context
#endif

struct thread_results { // to hold per thread results
  int nbr; // nbr of generated results
  int *results; // actual filtered numbers. Will write in subList table
};

// could be parallelized, but rand is not thread safe. drand48 should be
for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
  {
    hugeList[i] = (rand() % 100);//random integers from 0 to 99
  }

int *subList=(int *)malloc(HUGE*sizeof(int)); // table to hold thread results
   // this is more complex to have a 2D array here as max_thread and actual number of thread
   // are not known at compile time. VLA cannot be used (and array dim can be very large).
   // Concerning its size, it is possible to have ALL elements in hugeList selected and the array must be
   // dimensionned accordingly to avoid bugs.
struct thread_results* threadres=(struct thread_results *)malloc(thread_nbr*sizeof(struct thread_results));

#pragma omp parallel
{
// first declare and initialize thread vars
#ifdef _OPENMP
  int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num() ; // hold thread id
  int thread_nbr = omp_get_num_threads() ; // hold actual nbr of threads
#else
  // to ensure proper serial behavior
  int thread_id = 0;
  int thread_nbr = 1;
#endif

  struct thread_results *res=threadres+thread_id;
  res->nbr=0;
  // compute address in subList table
  res->results=subList+(HUGE/thread_nbr)*thread_id;
  int * res_ptr=res->results; // local pointer. Each thread points to independent part of subList table

  int n=0; // number of results. We want one per thread to only have local updates.
  #pragma omp for
  for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
  {

     if(hugeList[i] < 10)
     {
      //do something to fill "subList" properly
       res_ptr[n]=hugeList[i];
       n++;
     }
  }
  res->nbr=n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.
1. From "#pragma...", I do not know how to write.
2. Corrected.
3. "subList" is a 2D array. Length of one dimension is maxThreadNo. In this program, no. of element of the larger dimension is approx. 1,000,000/10/maxThreadNo.4.
4.OK 5.OK.

In your code, res_ptr[n]=hugeList[i]; caused "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Maybe res_ptr is not properly allocated?

Comment: More questions:
1. In "...omp for" section, n has different copies in each thread and any element of res_ptr may be written by any thread. Will it give right result?
2. I want 2D array as output, or maxThreadNo pieces of 1D arrays. It seems to be easy but I do not know the function. *results holds this 2D array as a long combined 1D. Is there a better way?

Comment: I have updated the answer and added explicative comments. Segfault problem was in pointer computation of the thread pointer in subList. Using a 2D array to store the results is much more complicated, because you do not know at compile time thread number. But it is doable with allocations.

Comment: I changed "#pragma omp parallel" to "#pragma omp for reduction(+: n)", otherwise neither subList nor n can be reproduced. (I don't know how "reduction" affects subList...If no "reduction" argument, subList elements are mostly 0.)

I will upload a new version of code that is reproducible based on yours.

Answer (score 0):

Updated complete codes based on @Alain Merigot 's answer
I tested the following code; It is reproducible (including presence & absence of #pragma arguments).
However, only the front elements of subList are correct, while the rest are empty.
(filename.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define HUGE 10000000
#define DELAY 1000 //depends on your CPU power

//use global variables to store desired results, otherwise can't be obtain outside "pragma"
int n = 0;// number of results. We want one per thread to only have local updates.
double *subList;// table to hold thread results

int main()
{
    double *hugeList = (double *)malloc(HUGE);
#ifdef _OPENMP
    int thread_nbr = omp_get_max_threads();
#else
    int thread_nbr = 1; // to ensure proper behavior in a sequential context
#endif

    struct thread_results
    {                    // to hold per thread results
        int nbr;         // nbr of generated results
        double *results; // actual filtered numbers. Will write in subList table
    };

    // could be parallelized, but rand is not thread safe. drand48 should be
    for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        hugeList[i] = sin(i); //fixed array content to test reproducibility
    }

    subList = (double *)malloc(HUGE * sizeof(double)); // table to hold thread results
                                                        // this is more complex to have a 2D array here as max_thread and actual number of thread
                                                        // are not known at compile time. VLA cannot be used (and array dim can be very large).
                                                        // Concerning its size, it is possible to have ALL elements in hugeList selected and the array must be
                                                        // dimensionned accordingly to avoid bugs.
    struct thread_results *threadres = (struct thread_results *)malloc(thread_nbr * sizeof(struct thread_results));

#pragma omp parallel
    {
// first declare and initialize thread vars
#ifdef _OPENMP
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();   // hold thread id
        int thread_nbr = omp_get_num_threads(); // hold actual nbr of threads
#else
        // to ensure proper serial behavior
        int thread_id = 0;
        int thread_nbr = 1;
#endif

        struct thread_results *res = threadres + thread_id;
        res->nbr = 0;
        // compute address in subList table
        res->results = subList + (HUGE / thread_nbr) * thread_id;
        double *res_ptr = res->results; // local pointer. Each thread points to independent part of subList table

#pragma omp for reduction(+ \
                          : n)
        for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DELAY; ++i){}//do nothing, just waste time

            if (hugeList[i] < 0)
            {
                //do something to fill "subList" properly
                res_ptr[n] = hugeList[i];
                n++;
            }
        }
        res->nbr = n;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("sublist %d: %lf\n", i, subList[i]);//show some elements of subList to check reproducibility
    }
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
}
```

Linux compile: gcc -o filename filename.c -fopenmp -lm

I hope there can be more discussion of the mechanism of this code.